# jquery detect window resize

Tags: jquery, dynamic, width, detect, window-resize

I have a question about a site I'm working on regarding detecting when the window is resized.  I know this has been discussed previously and I've read through many of the discussions and just couldn't get it to work.  I'm just learning jquery.

```
 $(function(){
    var viewPortWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewPortWidth > 1900)
    {
       $('#mainbio, #footerlinks').addClass('extraWide')
    }
    else if (viewPortWidth > 1400)
    {
       $('#mainbio, #footerlinks').addClass('wide')
    }
    else if (viewPortWidth > 1000) 
    {
       $('#mainbio, #footerlinks').addClass('standard')
    }
    else if (viewPortWidth > 700)
    {
       $('#mainbio, #footerlinks, #twitter, #facebook, #flickr,   #lastfm').addClass('narrow')
    }
    else 
    {
       $('#mainbio, #footerlinks, #twitter, #facebook, #flickr, #lastfm').addClass('extraNarrow')
    }
 });
```

This is what I have so far and it works fine, but only on the initial load.  I'm wondering if someone can help me adjust this so it will work dynamically - so I could see the changes if I were to manually resize my browser, without refreshing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can call back this function using `.resize()`.

e.g.

```
var detectViewPort = function(){
    var viewPortWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewPortWidth > 1900)
    //...The rest of your above code.
};

$(function(){
  detectViewPort();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
   detectViewPort();
});
```

There maybe another/better way around this but this is the option I know about.

Comment: @vietech - minor point, you missed out the ); at the end of the $(window).resize function.

Comment: So I did :) ... also missed it out on the `$(fun..` too... have added them to the answer

Comment: You would also need to .removeClass(OLDCLASS) each time

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, this is a self calling anonymous function so will be run immediately as soon as the page loads (therefore will run once).

To get it to run whenever the windows is resized you need to register the resize event on the window (the full documentation is here http://api.jquery.com/resize/).

If you update the line:

> $(function() {

so it reads

> $(window).resize(function() {

it will get called whenever the window browser is resized.

Comment: You are right but he would still need the `$(function(){` so it runs when the page is first loaded. Having just `resize()` would only run the function when the window is resized.

Comment: @vietech - indeed. That is true.

Comment: Thank you both for the replies.  I apologize, I know I'm probably doing something really stupid; but, I can update my line as you say and have it adjust when I scale the page down - but I break it when I try to add the function back so it still refreshes on the first load..?

Comment: @Jgammel When you say it breaks what happens?

Comment: I lose the added classes and it no longer scales like it was when I just edited the line as you suggested.

Comment: @Jgammel If you tried to use Viewtech's solution above he has missed out the `);` at the end of the $(window).resize() function

Comment: @Marryat Thank you - It seems to be working now.  One odd thing, and this isn't a big deal at all, more for my own curiosity.  It works fine when I refresh or when I manually drag the browser down in size, but if I ever try to manually drag/enlarge the browser window the changes don't register.  Any thoughts on why it would only work sizing down?  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Jgammel You are only ever adding in classes, you never remove any existing classes. If you use either firebug or the chrome developer tools to inspect the elements that you are modifying, they will have lots of these classes present. You will need to use .removeClass() to unpick the extra classes that you are addding.

Comment: @Marryat Ahhha.  Many thanks for your help on this issue.  I understand now.